# Lm74 thermometer bugs while on negative temperature using STM

Tags: stm32, spi, temperature

I want to measure temperature using lm74 temperature sensor:
https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/9026/NSC/LM74/113/3/LM74.html

I have connected it to my stm32L476 by SPI as shown on diagram: 
[Conection stm temperature sensor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rHjs.png)

Code to recive temperature (it is triggled by interuption every 1 s):

```
float TEMP_readTemp() {
    uint16_t temp_binary;

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_GPIO_Port, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &temp_binary, 1, 10);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CS_GPIO_Port, CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    float temp;
    temp = TEMP_ConvertTemp2(temp_binary);
    if (LOG_UART_ENAIBLE)
        TEST_UART_LogSTLink("Temp:  %s \n\r", FLOAT, &temp);
    return temp;
}
```

It shows a positive temperature ok. But when I have the temperature below 0 it shows -256.0625 every second record:

```
Temp:  -4.187500                                                                
Temp:  -256.062500                                                              
Temp:  -4.125000                                                                
Temp:  -256.062500                                                              
Temp:  -4.187500                                                                
Temp:  -256.062500                                                              
Temp:  -4.250000                                                                
Temp:  -256.062500                                                              
Temp:  -4.250000                                                                
Temp:  -256.062500                                                              
Temp:  -4.312500                                                                
Temp:  -256.062500                                                              
Temp:  -4.312500                                                                
Temp:  -256.062500                                                              
Temp:  -4.312500                                                                
Temp:  -256.062500
```

Any idea whats happening?

converting function:

```
float TEMP_ConvertTemp2(uint16_t arrayBoth) {
    uint16_t bitShift;
    int bitShift_int;
    uint16_t division;
    float temperature;
    if (arrayBoth & 0x8000) {
        division = arrayBoth - 1;
        division = ~division;
        bitShift = division >> 3;
        bitShift_int = (int) bitShift;
        temperature = (float) -1 * ((bitShift_int +1 )* LSB_CONST);
    } else {
        bitShift = arrayBoth >> 3;
        bitShift_int = (int) bitShift;
        temperature = bitShift_int * LSB_CONST;
    }
    return temperature;
}
```

Update:
Ok, I looked by oscilloscope to see it (today it was strange, every second record was wrong, no matter what temperature was (positive or negative)).

[CS and CLOCK osciloscope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNGMB.jpg)

[MISO and CLOCK osciloscope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MQWr.jpg)

Those photos show two measurements done one right after the another.  The first one is -256.0625,  secend is correct and is about +31.

Comment: `TEMP_ConvertTemp2(temp_binary);` source needed

Comment: This function works well. I have already checked on the oscilloscope and lm74 trully sends different things.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved this bug. You have to make a software pulldown on MOSI in my case it was configuring STM PIN correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TEMP_ConvertTemp2` is working as expected. as can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/rkcbMCqrm).

**Your error:**

According to the datasheet the temperature packet it returns 2 bytes big. (Eg. `0x4B07`) You only tell the SPI to return 1 byte. So change

```
HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &temp_binary, 1, 10);  // Receive 1 byte
```

to

```
HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, &temp_binary, 2, 10);  // Receive two bytes
```

**Update:**

Seems like the sensor is not really returning anything, as it's only returning a lot of `1`s with a `0` here and there. The two values you show only has one `0` each, and the idle value of the line is probably `1`. This seems erroneous. A few things you can look at:

- What does the `HAL_SPI_Receive` return? It should return `HAL_OK`.
- Do you have a oscilloscope? If you do, show a picture of what you observe. Is there a clock signal? Is the frequencies correct? Is the `CS` working as expected?
- Are you sure you are turning on the sensor correctly? Maybe it needs some configuration settings first?

Comment: I have already tried it. The result is not better:
After temperature falls below zero it captures only:
Temp:  -256.062500                                                              
Temp:  -0.187500                                                                
Temp:  -256.062500                                                              
Temp:  -0.187500
even when the temperature is positive again.

Comment: Yes it returns HAL_Ok in both cases.